# How to keep track of how many bytes written when using 'std::io::Write'?

Tags: io, rust

When writing to a binary file-format, its useful to be able to check how many bytes have been written (for alignment for example), or just to ensure nested functions wrote the correct amount of data.

Is there a way to inspect `std::io::Write` to know how much has been written? If not, what would be a good approach to wrap the writer so it could track how many bytes have been written?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Write` has two required methods: `write` and `flush`. Since `write` already returns the number of bytes written, you just track that:

```
use std::io::{self, Write};

struct ByteCounter<W> {
    inner: W,
    count: usize,
}

impl<W> ByteCounter<W>
    where W: Write
{
    fn new(inner: W) -> Self {
        ByteCounter {
            inner: inner,
            count: 0,
        }
    }

    fn into_inner(self) -> W {
        self.inner
    }

    fn bytes_written(&self) -> usize {
        self.count
    }
}

impl<W> Write for ByteCounter<W>
    where W: Write
{
    fn write(&mut self, buf: &[u8]) -> io::Result<usize> {
        let res = self.inner.write(buf);
        if let Ok(size) = res {
            self.count += size
        }
        res
    }

    fn flush(&mut self) -> io::Result<()> {
        self.inner.flush()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let out = std::io::stdout();
    let mut out = ByteCounter::new(out);
    writeln!(&mut out, "Hello, world! {}", 42).unwrap();
    println!("Wrote {} bytes", out.bytes_written());
}
```

It's important to *not* delegate `write_all` or `write_fmt` because these do not return the count of bytes. Delegating them would allow bytes to be written and not tracked.

Comment: This is an excellent answer too, would be nice to mark both as correct!

Comment: @ideasman42 I would not mind if you mark this as answer, as this also applies if `Seek` is not or cannot be implemented.

Comment: @wimh eh, I dunno. Accepting is up to whatever helps the OP the most in their specific case. Upvotes come to the answers that future people find useful.

Comment: Is there a crate defining this struct? It seems to be handy, and I don't want to reinvent it everywhere.

Comment: @SOFe it probably is somewhere, but I don't know where.

Comment: I ended up making a library for that: https://docs.rs/count-write

Answer (score 6):

If the type you write to implements [`std::io::Seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html), you can use `seek` to get the current position:

```
pos = f.seek(SeekFrom::Current(0))?;
```

`Seek` is implemented by [`std::fs::File`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html) (and [`std::io::BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html) if the wrapped type implements `Seek` too).

---

So the function signature:

```
use ::std::io::{Write, Seek, SeekFrom, Error};

fn my_write<W: Write>(f: &mut W) -> Result<(), Error> { ... }
```

Needs to have the `Seek` trait added:

```
fn my_write<W: Write + Seek>(f: &mut W) -> Result<(), Error> { ... }
```